# JavascriptSerializer serializing property twice when "new" used in subclass

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

Trying to create a service to return an object that has many shared properties, but one property should be highly limited in some situations. This is resulting in odd and undesired behaviour, where a property name is reused in the serialized output, resulting in incorrect behaviour in the browser. Here is an example that can be pasted into LINQPad (if you add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions`) to see the problem:

```
void Main()
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    json.Serialize(new Full(true)).Dump();
    json.Serialize(new Limited()).Dump();
}

public class Full
{
    public String Stuff { get { return "Common things"; }  }
    public FullStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Full(bool includestatus)
    {
        if(includestatus)
            Status = new FullStatus();
    }
}

public class Limited : Full
{
    public new LimitedStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Limited() : base(false)
    {
        Status = new LimitedStatus();
    }
}

public class FullStatus 
{
    public String Text { get { return "Loads and loads and loads of things"; } }
}

public class LimitedStatus 
{
    public String Text { get { return "A few things"; } }
}
```

This prints:

```
{"Stuff":"Common things","Status":{"Text":"Loads and loads and loads of things"}}
{"Status":{"Text":"A few things"},"Stuff":"Common things","Status":null}
```

When JSON.parse is called in the browser, the second Status overrides the first, meaning Status is always null.

The only way I can see of fixing this is to refactor so that FullStatus and LimitedStatus both inherit from a common parent and use `override` rather that `new` - bit more complicated in the real world code, but possible. Is my assumption correct? And also, I'd be interested to know if this is expected behaviour or a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.  The `new` keyword is not the same as `override`; it merely "hides" the base class property, but the original property is still there and can still be discovered via reflection (which is how serializers do their work).

Generally, it is considered a "[code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)" to define a method or property in a base class and then replace it with another method or property in a derived class that takes away functionality of the base class.  This violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Instead of deriving `Limited` from `Full`, I would propose that you make an abstract base class for them and put the common stuff in there.  Then, you can ADD things to each subclass which are different or exclusive to each (i.e. your differently-typed `Status` members).

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = 
            new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        Console.WriteLine(json.Serialize(new Full(true)));
        Console.WriteLine(json.Serialize(new Limited()));
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public String Stuff { get { return "Common things"; } }
}

public class Full : Base
{
    public FullStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Full(bool includestatus)
    {
        if (includestatus)
            Status = new FullStatus();
    }
}

public class Limited : Base
{
    public LimitedStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Limited()
    {
        Status = new LimitedStatus();
    }
}

public class FullStatus
{
    public String Text { get { return "Loads and loads and loads of things"; } }
}

public class LimitedStatus
{
    public String Text { get { return "A few things"; } }
}
```

Output:

```
{"Status":{"Text":"Loads and loads and loads of things"},"Stuff":"Common things"}
{"Status":{"Text":"A few things"},"Stuff":"Common things"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I marked your answer as correct as it is the route I went down - serves me right for trying to hack something in quickly in the first place. I'd still be interested in the reason behind the serializers behaviour, but I guess as the JSON is generates is perfectly valid (well, in Chrome at least - the earlier property is silently ignored) it's not a bug in the serializer, just something for the programmer to fix in their model.

Comment: You mean why does the serializer output two properties with the same name in the same object?  Normally it wouldn't, but when you use the "new" keyword to hide a property, the serializer finds two properties with the same name when it reflects over the object, and I guess it's not doing any checking for that situation when it writes the JSON.  Having two properties with the same name in the same object in JSON is not technically invalid per [the spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159), but it does make the JSON less interoperable.  (continued)

Comment: Some parsers, including Json.Net itself, ironically, cannot handle objects containing duplicate property names during deserialization.  For this reason, it is considered bad form to create JSON with duplicate property names, and is best avoided if possible.