# Json.Net cannot serialize property of a class derived from dictionary

Tags: serialization, json.net

I have a class that is derived from Dictionary. Also the class itself has a `ClientId` property. I want to de-serialize the collection of this class into JSON string using `Json.Net` So followed the documentation [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm)

```
public interface IClientSettings: IDictionary<string, string>
{        
    string ClientId { get; set; }        
}

public class ClientSettings : Dictionary<string, string>, IClientSettings
{        
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

and then I am de-serializing list into string

```
        var list = new List<IClientSettings>();

        var client1 = new ClientSettings();
        client1.ClientId = "Client1";
        client1.Add("key1", "value1");
        client1.Add("key2", "value2");
        client1.Add("key3", "value3");

        var client2 = new ClientSettings();
        client1.ClientId = "Client2";
        client2.Add("key1", "value1");
        client2.Add("key2", "value2");
        client2.Add("key3", "value3");

        list.Add(client1);
        list.Add(client2);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
```

However this does not serialize `Clientid` property. Below is the output.

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
]
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. I have also found suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265629/how-do-i-get-json-net-to-serialize-members-of-a-class-deriving-from-listt) that suggest to do custom serialization, is that the only option I have?

Comment: Is there a reason you're deriving from dictionary instead of having a dictionary property?  You can get around this very easily with a simple class with 2 properties, string ClientID and Dictionary<string,string> whatever.  It serializes fine as such(too long, just as above, string, dict)... output -[{"myDict":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},"ClientID":"Client1"},{"myDict":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},"ClientID":"Client2"}]

Comment: Class mentioned in prior comment.
[Serializable]
    public class ClientSettings
    {
        public string ClientID { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> myDict;
        public ClientSettings()
        {
            myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public void Add(string key, string value)
        {
            myDict.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct, you will need to do some sort of custom serialization.  Json.NET will either serialize the key/value pairs of the dictionary as a JSON object (using [`JsonDictionaryContract`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonDictionaryContract.htm)), or the properties of the dictionary as a JSON object (using [`JsonObjectContract`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract.htm)) if you mark the type with [`[JsonObject]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm) - but not both.  I suspect doing both was not implemented to thereby avoid the possibility of run-time name clashes when the dictionary contains a key with the same name as a property, e.g.:

```
var client3 = new ClientSettings();
client3.ClientId = "Client1";
client3["ClientId"] = "Conflicting Value";
```

According to the [IETF standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6),

> When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.

Thus this is a situation best avoided.

One possible implementation is as follows:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ClientSettings : Dictionary<string, string>, IClientSettings
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    IDictionary<string, string> Items { get { return new DictionaryWrapper<string, string>(this); } }
}
```

Using

```
public class DictionaryWrapper<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;

    public DictionaryWrapper(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) { dictionary.Add(key, value); }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) { return dictionary.ContainsKey(key); }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys { get { return dictionary.Keys; } }

    public bool Remove(TKey key) { return dictionary.Remove(key); }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) { return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value); }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values { get { return dictionary.Values; } }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[key]; }
        set { dictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) { dictionary.Add(item); }

    public void Clear() { dictionary.Clear(); }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) { return dictionary.Contains(item); }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex) { dictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); }

    public int Count { get { return dictionary.Count; } }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return dictionary.IsReadOnly; } }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) { return dictionary.Remove(item); }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() { return dictionary.GetEnumerator(); }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    #endregion
}
```

`MemberSerialization.OptIn` is used to prevent base class properties such as `Count`, `Comparer`, `Keys` and `Values` from being serialized.

With this, your JSON will look like:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "ClientId": "Client2",
>     "Items": {
>       "key1": "value1",
>       "key2": "value2",
>       "key3": "value3"
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```