# JavaScriptSerializer throwing AmbiguousMatchException when “new” used in subclass

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, javascriptserializer

I know that the same problem is faced by a lot of people in one way or another but what I'm confused about is that how come Newtonsoft JSON Serializer is able to correctly handle this case while JavaScriptSerializer fails to do so.

I'm going to use the same code sample used in one of the other stackoverflow thread ([JavascriptSerializer serializing property twice when "new" used in subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215578/javascriptserializer-serializing-property-twice-when-new-used-in-subclass))

```
void Main()
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    var json = serializer.Serialize(new Limited());
    Limited status = serializer.Deserialize<Limited>(json); --> throws AmbiguousMatchException
}

public class Full
{
    public String Stuff { get { return "Common things"; }  }
    public FullStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Full(bool includestatus)
    {
        if(includestatus)
            Status = new FullStatus();
    }
}

public class Limited : Full
{
    public new LimitedStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Limited() : base(false)
    {
        Status = new LimitedStatus();
    }
}

public class FullStatus 
{
    public String Text { get { return "Loads and loads and loads of things"; } }
}

public class LimitedStatus 
{
    public String Text { get { return "A few things"; } }
}
```

But if I use Newtonsoft Json Serializer, everythings works fine. Why? And is it possible to achieve the same using JavaScriptSerializer?

```
void Main()
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Limited());
    Limited status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Limited>(json);  ----> Works fine.
}
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but I believe you want to be using     Serializer.deserialize<Limited>(json);

Comment: The LimitedStatus is something different to a FullStatus and you hide a public base class property. In my opinion this model should have a base class with the Stuff property and descendants should implement behavior using Interfaces for FullStatus and LimitedStatus, not with same property names. JavaScript serializer will clearly understand what it needs to do then. Also, why not use the DatacontractJsonSerializer?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this works in Json.NET is that it has specific code to handle this situation.  From [JsonPropertyCollection.cs](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/ee170dc5510bb3ffd35fc1b0d986f34e33c51ab9/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonPropertyCollection.cs#L63):

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a <see cref="JsonProperty"/> object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="property">The property to add to the collection.</param>
public void AddProperty(JsonProperty property)
{
    if (Contains(property.PropertyName))
    {
        // don't overwrite existing property with ignored property
        if (property.Ignored)
            return;
        JsonProperty existingProperty = this[property.PropertyName];
        bool duplicateProperty = true;
        if (existingProperty.Ignored)
        {
            // remove ignored property so it can be replaced in collection
            Remove(existingProperty);
            duplicateProperty = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (property.DeclaringType != null && existingProperty.DeclaringType != null)
            {
                if (property.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(existingProperty.DeclaringType))
                {
                    // current property is on a derived class and hides the existing
                    Remove(existingProperty);
                    duplicateProperty = false;
                }
                if (existingProperty.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(property.DeclaringType))
                {
                    // current property is hidden by the existing so don't add it
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        if (duplicateProperty)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("A member with the name '{0}' already exists on '{1}'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, property.PropertyName, _type));
    }
    Add(property);
}
```

As you can see above, there is specific code here to prefer derived class properties over base class properties of the same name and visibility.

[`JavaScriptSerializer` has no such logic](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/ObjectConverter.cs,809b4f13600ad28c).  It simply calls [`Type.GetProperty(string, flags)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
        PropertyInfo propInfo = serverType.GetProperty(memberName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public);
```

This method is [documented to throw an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in exactly this situation:

> Situations in which AmbiguousMatchException occurs include the following:
>
> - A type contains two indexed properties that have the same name but different numbers of parameters. To resolve the ambiguity, use an overload of the GetProperty method that specifies parameter types.
> - A derived type declares a property that hides an inherited property with the same name, using the new modifier (Shadows in Visual Basic). To resolve the ambiguity, include BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly to restrict the search to members that are not inherited.

I don't know why Microsoft didn't add logic for this to `JavaScriptSerializer`.  It's really a very simple piece of code; perhaps it got eclipsed by `DataContractJsonSerializer`?

You do have a workaround, which is to write a custom [`JavaScriptConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class LimitedConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    const string StuffName = "Stuff";
    const string StatusName = "Status";

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var limited = new Limited();
        object value;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(StuffName, out value))
        {
            // limited.Stuff = serializer.ConvertToType<string>(value); // Actually it's get only.
        }
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(StatusName, out value))
        {
            limited.Status = serializer.ConvertToType<LimitedStatus>(value);
        }

        return limited;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var limited = (Limited)obj;
        if (limited == null)
            return null;
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (limited.Stuff != null)
            dict.Add(StuffName, limited.Stuff);
        if (limited.Status != null)
            dict.Add(StatusName, limited.Status);
        return dict;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new [] { typeof(Limited) } ; }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
        try
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new LimitedConverter() });

            var json = serializer.Serialize(new Limited());
            Debug.WriteLine(json);
            var status = serializer.Deserialize<Limited>(json);
            var json2 = serializer.Serialize(status);
            Debug.WriteLine(json2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString()); // NO ASSERT.
        }
```